# No `data` communication between django-push-notifications and Service Worker

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, service-worker, web-push, django-push-notifications

I have been tinkering with [`django-push-notifications`](https://github.com/jleclanche/django-push-notifications), followed a [google tutorial](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/push-notifications).

My current status is a web which seems to work and register and asks for notifications permissions and so on. I am running through `./manage.py runserver` and using `localhost:8000`. The Service Worker is currently working (as expected?). When I perform a `device.send_message("Hello world")` (through the `push_notification` module) I can see that I receive an `event` in the Javascript application. Currently testing in Chrome, I plan to tailor it for Android.

No matter what I try, the `event.data` is always `Null`. I have tried sending regular messages, structured messages, and the keyword argument `extra` for the `send_message` method with no luck.

I assume that I am missing something?

Snippets of what I am running (incomplete, but not sure what is relevant)

```
# Trigger push notifications
device = GCMDevice.objects.all()
device.send_message(<some data here>, extra=<some data here>)
```

And regarding the Javascript in the Service Worker:

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
    console.log('Push message', event);

    var data = {};
    if (event.data) {
        data = event.data.json();
    }
    console.log('Push data', data);
    ...
```

Regarding the set-up and registration:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js').then(function () {
    return navigator.serviceWorker.ready;
}).then(function (serviceWorkerRegistration) {
    return serviceWorkerRegistration.pushManager.subscribe({userVisibleOnly: true})
}).then(function (pushSubscription) {
    // Last part of the URL is indeed the Registration ID for the GCM
    var reg_id = pushSubscription.endpoint.split('/').pop();
    console.log('Subscribed! Endpoint:', reg_id);

    // Send the registration_id, which is the only required field
    return $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: "{% url 'api:gcmdevice-list' %}",
        data: {registration_id: reg_id}
    });
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.log('Service Worker Error:', error);
});
```

Which is the correct way of transfering information from Django to the notification?

Comment: Have you checked `event.data` is `null`? Perhaps the call to `.json()` is returning `null`? Can you try doing `event.date.text()` instead?

Comment: From the Chrome console I can see that `event.data` is `null`, from the beginning.

Comment: I think there is something wrong with the implementation, can you try [django-webpush](https://github.com/safwanrahman/django-webpush) instead?

Comment: @Salva Thanks for the suggestion, I detected some differences regarding `p256dh`, which drove me to understand what they mean. However, at the moment I am unsuccessful with `django-webpush` to work (some `AppRegistryNotReady` exception) and it doesn't quite fit my data model right now. I will keep trying.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the implementation of django-push-notifications does **not** support web push encryption, which is required in order to send information from the server to the client (according to [google](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/web-push-encryption) and also to [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Push_API/Using_the_Push_API)).

That means that either I change to another implementation (like [`django-webpush`](https://github.com/safwanrahman/django-webpush) as @Salva suggested), or I add support for that in `django-push-notifications`.

I honestly think that that is the problem, but I am not completely sure.

Edit: Third option, roll my own using [`pywebpush`](https://github.com/web-push-libs/pywebpush/). Given that I already had the JS stuff in place, it wasn't so hard. If I had to start over, maybe I would look closer to `django-webpush`.